# Cross Compiling - Platform Vs Architecture

Tags: compiling, cross-compilation

Could someone explain, what is the precise definition of cross compilation.
I am asking this because.

- When a program is compiled to a different platform (operating system) other than the host platform on which the code is compiled, many refer to this as cross compilation.

Eg : Compiling for Linux arm on Windows.

- On the other hand, If you compile a program on Linux desktop ( i386 architecture ) to be run on Linux arm (ARM architecture). Does this process can be called as cross compilation ?

Thank you.

Comment: Related: [What is cross compilation?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/897289/12892) (from Stack Overflow).

Comment: Have you read [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compilation)? What part of the article don't you understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term platform includes all the details regarding the computer on which the program is compiled or/and run. This means stuff like:

- CPU: instruction set (x86, x86_64, ARM), endianess (big endian, littel endian)
- compiler: language (e.g. C90, C99, C11), vendor (GCC, LLVM)
- libraries, for example glibc and BSD libc, malloc and jemalloc
- operating system

When the platform on which the program is compiled is different than the one on which it is run, you're dealing with cross compilation. In your specific case the CPU is different.

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive answer. This answers my question.

Comment: @VijayRajanna, then please select it as accepted.